# To Prove $\text{Arg}(\bar{z}) = -\text{Arg}(z)$ if $z$ is not real.

Tags: complex-numbers

In complex analysis,

To Prove $\text{Arg}(\bar{z}) = -\text{Arg}(z)$, is it enough to show that $\arg(\bar{z}) = -\arg(z)$?

If not, what additional proof do I need?

Comment: That's amazing that you've asked so many questions so far, and not once tried to learn how to format it right.

Comment: Is there a difference between arg and Arg?

Comment: We define Arg is principal value of the arg

Comment: What is the principal value of arg?

Answer (score 1):

**Definitions :**

$Arg(z)$ is the principle argument of $z$ and $-\pi < Arg(z) \leq \pi$.

$\arg(z)=\{Arg (z)+2\pi k | k \in \mathbb Z \}$

That is $\arg(z)$ is a set (multi-valued) and $Arg(z)$ is single valued.

**Solution :**

Suppose that $z$ is not real.

So $Arg(z)= \frac{\pi}{2}$ or $Arg(z)= -\frac{\pi}{2}$

**Case I : $Arg(z)= \frac{\pi}{2}$**

If $Arg(z)= \frac{\pi}{2}$ , then $Arg(\overline{z})= -\frac{\pi}{2}$

$\Rightarrow Arg(\overline{z})=-Arg(z)$.

Similarly the second case.